# pipenv and Atom packages

Tags: atom-editor, pipenv

I'm trying to download few Python packages for Atom with pipenv but Atom can't "see it". The pop-ups says it's not installed:

```
flake8==3.7.8
- entrypoints [required: >=0.3.0,<0.4.0, installed: 0.3]
- mccabe [required: >=0.6.0,<0.7.0, installed: 0.6.1]
- pycodestyle [required: >=2.5.0,<2.6.0, installed: 2.5.0]
- pyflakes [required: >=2.1.0,<2.2.0, installed: 2.1.1]

autopep8==1.4.4
- pycodestyle [required: >=2.4.0, installed: 2.5.0]
```

Clearly it is installed. What can I do ? Before you ask, I did restart the editor.

Answer (score 0):

install one of Terminal packages for Atom, run it and then :

```
cd "the_path_to_the_directory"
```

`pipenv shell python3`(or `python` depending on your OS) `name_of_your_script.py`